# How to get header data from server response in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic2

Im still fairly new to ionic2 so any resources, libraries or code samples would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This link a answer for your question:
http://www.joshmorony.com/using-http-to-fetch-remote-data-from-a-server-in-ionic-2/